# Automated skinning in A-pose

Tags: rigging

The game that I'm working on has a pipeline requirement of creating clothing with the main character in A-pose (clothing is created in Clo3D), as this helps the clothing look better in most natural poses. However, the amount of clothing produced is significant (in the hundreds), and the clothing being in A-pose causes the few auto-skinning solutions I've tried (such as [Voxel Heat Diffuse Skinning](https://blendermarket.com/products/voxel-heat-diffuse-skinning)) to fail, most notably around the shoulders and armpits. Does anyone have experience with mass automated skinning of A-pose models that could help here?

[image]

Comment: Could you use the Data Transfer modifier to transfer the weights of the character's body to the clothing?

Comment: @BrockoliBruce thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately that still causes issues around the armpit like shown in the imaged attached in the topic, especially on baggier clothing...

Comment: In that case, could you transfer the weights from clothes where the weight painting is fixed instead? I hope I don't sound redundant.